# Can torsion be developed in homology of finite index subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The first homology of a group G, denoted $H_1(G)$ is just the abelianization of G, i.e. G/[G,G].

Suppose that G is a group with $H_1(G)$ torsion-free. If H is a finite index subgroup, is $H_1(H)$ torsion-free?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that $H_1(G) \cong G/G'$. The answer is not necessarily. I can think of an example with $H_1(G) \cong {\mathbb Z}^2$, $|G'|=2$ having an abelian subgroup of index 2 that is not torsion-free.

Comment: Thanks Derek - I edited my question to include this. I would be interested in your example. A follow-up question would be- Are there any conditions that would ensure that $H_1(H)$ stays torsion-free? An example would be this trivially holds for free groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example was the class 2 nilpotent group

$G=\langle x,y,z \mid [x,y]=z, z^2=1, [x,z]=[y,z]=1 \rangle$

with $H = \langle x^2,y,z \rangle$, but in fact it works just as well without the relation $z^2=1$ of $G$, which gives a torsion-free example. So it's hard to think of conditions on $G$ that make it work!

Comment: I have two probably stupid questions ;-).                1) Is it obvious that H has index 2 in G?                2) I couldn't see how it worked without using the $z^2 = 1$ relation?  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The subgroup $\langle z \rangle$ is equal to $G'$. So, since $z \in H$, $|G:H| = |G/G':H/G'| = 2$, because $G/G'$ is a free abelian group of rank 2. If you leave out the relation $z^2=1$, then you still have  $\langle z \rangle = G'$ and $[x^2,y] = z^2$, so $H' = \langle z^2 \rangle$, and $z$ maps onto an element of order 2 in $H/H'$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense now. My original interest here was for G a right-angled Artin group. I'm guessing that this also doesn't hold, but I'll have to think about it. Thanks!